# Question about computing expected value of the limit of a geometric mean of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

If I have the random variables $ X_{i} $ for $ i=1  \ldots N$ with the random variables being randomly selected *integers* from $1$ to $9$, how would I calculate the expected value of  $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{N} X_{i} \right)^{\dfrac{1}{N}} . $$ This is obviously just the limit as $N$ goes to infinity of the geometric mean of N randomly selected integers from 1 to 9.

I'm wondering not only the answer but first how you would go about solve a problem like this. I haven't taken real higher-that-intro-level probability classes so my only knowledge of probability is a pretty dry and not very intensive 1st year college course on statistics and probability. Though I do have extensive math knowledge outside of that specific topic (Calculus, PDEs, Fourier Analysis, Abstract Algebra). Is there even a real number value that could be calculated from this question? I'm really just doing this out of my own curiosity (after reading [this Wikipedia page on Khinchin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin's_constant)) I'm not cheating on math homework or something like that.

Comment: The $0$ kills things. The tiny probability of a lengthy run of non-zeros makes no difference, as quick estimates will confirm.  If we didn't have the $0$, an argument with the logarithm would do it.

Comment: AHHH SORRY 1 to N. EDITED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [strong law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) for i.i.d. integrable sequences, $$\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\log X_i\to\nu\quad\text{almost surely},$$ where $\nu=E(\log X_1)$. This is equivalent to the assertion that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{N} X_{i} \right)^{1/N}=\mathrm e^\nu\quad\text{almost surely},$$ hence the expected value of the LHS exists and is $\mathrm e^\nu$. Numerically, $\mathrm e^\nu=(9!)^{1/9}\approx4.147166$.

A heuristics to understand this result is that, for every integer $1\leqslant k\leqslant9$, the number of times $T_N(k)$ that $X_i=k$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant N$ is roughly $\frac19N$ in the sense that $T_N(k)=\frac19N+o(N)$ (this is again the strong law of large numbers, but applied once for each $k$). Thus, almost surely, $$\left( \prod_{i = 1}^{N} X_{i} \right)^{1/N}=\prod_{k=1}^9k^{T_N(k)/N}\approx\prod_{k=1}^9k^{1/9}.$$ Similarly, for every function $A$, $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{N} A(X_{i}) \right)^{1/N}=\left(\prod_{k=1}^9A(k)\right)^{1/9}\quad\text{almost surely}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is my crack at the question, please if anybody sees any flaws, point them out

I am assuming that $X_{i}$'s are independent. From this it is important to know that 
$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}=e^{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(X_{i})}$$

Well notice that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(X_{i})$ is just the average of the log of the $X_{i}$ and we know that as $N\rightarrow \infty$ that the average will resemble a normal distribution by Central Limit Theorem. Thus since 
$$E(\ln (X))=\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{9}\ln(i)\right)\approx1.422426$$
and 
$$Var\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln (X_{i})\right)=\frac{V(\ln (X))}{N}=\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{9}\left(\ln(i)-1.422426\right)^{2}\right)\right)\approx\frac{0.4598559}{N}$$
Thus we have $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(X_{i})\sim N(1.422426,\frac{0.4598559}{N})$ approximately for large N. Thus this means that $e^{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(X_{i})}$ is lognormal where expected value of lognormal is 
$$E\left(e^{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln(X_{i})}\right)=e^{E(X)+\frac{1}{2}Var(X)}=e^{1.422426+\frac{0.4598559}{2N}}$$
Now if you can prove that 
$$E\left(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}\right)$$
which is held true by dominated convergence theorem (http://web.stanford.edu/class/msande322/docs/app_B.pdf) since the geometric mean in this case will always be bounded by arithmetic mean which has a finite expectation which would just be $E(X)$. Thus finally the expectation should just be $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}e^{1.422426+\frac{0.4598559}{2N}}=e^{1.422426}\approx4.147169$$