# How can I determine the probability of a number in a random sequence being of a cerrtain type?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables

I would like to produce some kind of probability function/density for finding out the likelihood of a chosen number, $k$, to occur in a random sequence of length, $N$.

---

**For Example:**

Let's say we have a sequence of $N=1000$, random numbers in the range $\in [0,1]$. Furthermore, let's truncate the random numbers to have only 3 significant digits (0.001).

How can I calculate how many times a particular *"even"* modulo number is expected to occur, such that we have the probability of:

- `(a)` $k \in [0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9]$
- `(b)` $k \in [0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.09]$
- `(c)` $k \in [0.02, 0.05, 0.08]$

---

Possibly related questions:

- [An integer is chosen at random from the first 1000 positive integers. Probability that is a multiple of both 6 and 8?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933648/an-integer-is-chosen-at-random-from-the-first-1000-positive-integers-probabilit)
- [Question about computing expected value of the limit of a geometric mean of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891716/question-about-computing-expected-value-of-the-limit-of-a-geometric-mean-of-rand)

---

PS. It's quite likely I have not stated the title of this question correctly, please feel free to adjust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking only at numbers with three decimal places, your sample space has just $1000$ possible outcomes. For any particular set of $n$ outcomes the probability that each choice is in that set is just $p = n/1000$. (Your examples have $n= 9$, $9$ and $3$.) Since the choices are independent, the number of successes is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The expected number of successes in $N$ tries is then just $Np$.

Comment: After reading your answer, I think I've oversimplified what I actually wanted to do, because my *"random"* samples are not independent, but rather like a random-walk. However, that would now be off-topic. but out of curiosity, how would that affect the above? Also, what should I google or search for?

Comment: @not2qubit You have not provided enough information yet, Ask another question with a more careful description of your problem. Include ab example of your "samples" and what you would expect for output.